# Hover effect assistance on a div and h ref tags

Tags: html, css, mousehover

For some reason on my the website I am developing I can't figure out how to get my a hrefs to change when you hover over the boxes like the everything else inside of it. Here is the website link: http://wowbbq.michaellgray.com/

Thank you,

Comment: Post your CSS mate...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you need to apply the effect when user hovers over the graybtn div, not the anchor tag itself...

```
.graybtn:hover a{ color: white }
```

OR

```
.pork:hover .viewallbtn a{ color: white  }
```

Comment: div.viewallbtn {
    font-family: 'fira_sansmedium';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;  
    color: #426085 !important;
    border: 3px solid #426085;
    height: 40px;
    width: 190px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    padding-top: .4rem;
    margin: 2rem auto 0rem auto;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

div.viewallbtn a {
    color: #426085 !important;
}

Comment: .viewallbtn a:hover {
  font-family: 'fira_sansmedium';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff !important;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    height: 40px;
    width: 190px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    padding-top: .4rem;
        margin: -.7rem auto 0rem auto;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  display:block;
  }

Comment: The menu css for the different foods is: .apps {
    background-image: url("http://wowbbq.michaellgray.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/appsgray.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:cover;
      padding-bottom: 3rem;
    background-position: center;
   margin-bottom:2rem;
    color: #426085;
  }

.apps:hover {
   background-image: url("http://wowbbq.michaellgray.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/appsblue.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:cover;
  color:#fff;
  }

Comment: the 1st one worked for the learn more, going to play around with the other and see. Thank you,

Comment: And .menu:hover .viewallbtn a{ color: white  } didn't work?

Comment: works now, had to remove another css line. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped